# Google Maps Autocomplete doesn't work on 2 pages (2 different forms)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

Here's the setup of Google Autocomplete:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {       

        var from1_input = document.getElementById('autocomplete_from1'); // website.com/page1
        var to1_input   = document.getElementById('autocomplete_to1');   // website.com/page1         
        var from2_input = document.getElementById('autocomplete_from2'); // website.com/page2
        var to2_input   = document.getElementById('autocomplete_to2');   // website.com/page2

        var autocomplete_from1_input = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(from1_input); // website.com/page1 
        var autocomplete_to_1_input  = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(to1_input);   // website.com/page1
        var autocomplete_from2_input = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(from2_input); // website.com/page2
        var autocomplete_to2_input   = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(to2_input);   // website.com/page2            
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
```

The problem is that the form is on the **/page1** is working well, but on the **/page2** the autocomplete doesn't work.

I've try to delete the javascript for the **page1** and Google autocomplete is working well there, so it means that the Autocomplete is working either on the **page1** or on the **page2**, but unfortunately now on both.

The IDs are correct.

Why is that? Is there any restriction from Google's end or do I overlook something?

Thank you guys.

**EDIT:**

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places,geometry" %>
```

is included in the header.

Comment: Could I know what it's down voted? I am trying to figure it out, but still don't know the problem of it.

Answer (score 0):

So you have a page with the inputs  `#autocomplete_from1` and `#autocomplete_to1` and another page with the inputs `#autocomplete_from2` and `#autocomplete_to2` ?

Browsers stop the script-execution when an error occurs, when you are in page2 the error occurs here:

```
var autocomplete_from1_input = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(from1_input);
```

...because the input doesn't exist, the following statements will not be executed.

You must avoid this error. There are different possible solutions, e.g. a try/catch-statement

```
function initialize() {       

   //try to run the code for page1
 try{
    var from1_input = document.getElementById('autocomplete_from1'); 
    var to1_input   = document.getElementById('autocomplete_to1');  
    var autocomplete_from1_input = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(from1_input); 
    var autocomplete_to_1_input  = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(to1_input);   
   }
   //in case of an error run code for page2
 catch(e){
    var from2_input = document.getElementById('autocomplete_from2'); 
    var to2_input = document.getElementById('autocomplete_to2');   
    var autocomplete_from2_input = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(from2_input); 
    var autocomplete_to2_input = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(to2_input);   
   }
}
```