# Google's autocomplete doesn't work on page 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, autocomplete

HTML

```
 <input id="location_input" type="text" name="location" value="" placeholder="Location" class="0 text-center" style="width:200px;margin:0 auto;" required>
```

SCRIPT

```
 <script>
function initMap() {
  var input = /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(
      document.getElementById('location_input'));
  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
    infowindow.close();
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    if (!place.geometry) {
      window.alert("Autocomplete's returned place contains no geometry");
      return;
    }
    var address = '';
    if (place.address_components) {
      address = [
        (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
        (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
        (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
      ].join(' ');
    }
    infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' + address);
  });

  document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
    geocodeAddress(geocoder);
  });
}

function geocodeAddress(geocoder) {
  var address = document.getElementById('location_input').value;
  geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    //alert('Geocode was successful: ' + results[0].geometry.location);
    //function to call php to submit form.
    } else {
     // alert('Please try a broader location instead' + status);
    }
  });
}
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDmjFZ2NOW5-lGO9U2Wjlzt5-ekLANM8S0&signed_in=true&libraries=places&callback=initMap"
        async defer></script>
```

The same html and script I placed in page 2, but it doesn't overlay the autocomplete here. So I changed the id here from **location_input** to **location_input2** on HTML and script, yet it doesn't work.

I don't understand why its working on page1 but not in page2. I even tried disabling the script on page1 to see if that affect page2 but no changes made. I also referred [here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26317161/google-maps-autocomplete-doesnt-work-on-2-pages-2-different-forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26317161/google-maps-autocomplete-doesnt-work-on-2-pages-2-different-forms). But nothing helps.

PAGE 2

HTML

```
 <input id="location_input2" type="text" name="location" value="" placeholder="Location" class="0 text-center" style="width:200px;margin:0 auto;" required>
```

SCRIPT

```
<script>
function initMap() {
  var input = /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} *///(
  document.getElementById('location_input2'));
  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
    infowindow.close();
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    if (!place.geometry) {
      window.alert("Autocomplete's returned place contains no geometry");
      return;
    }
    var address = '';
    if (place.address_components) {
      address = [
        (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
        (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
        (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
      ].join(' ');
    }
    infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' + address);
  });

  document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
    geocodeAddress(geocoder);
  });
}

function geocodeAddress(geocoder) {
  var address = document.getElementById('location_input2').value;
  geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    //alert('Geocode was successful: ' + results[0].geometry.location);
    //function to call php to submit form.
    } else {
      //alert('Please try a broader location instead' + status);
    }
  });
}
    </script>
   <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDmjFZ2NOW5-lGO9U2Wjlzt5-ekLANM8S0&signed_in=true&libraries=places&callback=initMap"
        async defer></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the best practice is to **not share the api key in public** in forums.
Secondly, on your query, I believe there should be a **second initialization** for the new **input box** if the **page is not refreshing** in server side.
If you're playing with php pages, it will work well on page two.
If not please initialise the second text box on another id and grab that id to initialize function using jQuery.
like:

```
$('.firstTextbox).click(//call init for first);
$('.secondTextbox).click(//call init for second);
```

Hope the theory part is clear for you now. 
I can help you more if you can share your second page's code.

Comment: @Keren calling script again and again will make the google server block your second call blocked,
So, you have to dynamically switch between each text box using the one you click and then calling the init from that click function.

Comment: I did it by placing it in footer page instead of individual page where it will share same id and only one script called

Comment: @karen Good to know it worked for you. Happy coding.!

Answer (score 0):

I just removed extra slashes from you code and it works for me..

```
var input = /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(
```

Try it..